# How to write expression tag within scriptlet tag in jsp?

Tags: jsp

Here is the example of what i am asking

```
<%
String variable="Value";
out.println("<input type='hidden' value="<%=variable%>" "/);
%>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Answer (score 0):

In the Scriptlet you can use the java syntax like this:

```
<%
String variable="Value";
out.println("<input type='hidden' value='" + variable + "'>");
%>
```

But you should try avoiding scriptlets at all. Read more:
[How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)